# why fullcalendar does't render inside modal but does without

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

can someone please tell me why calendars don't show in the modal? But without modal they do show just fine.
See this first where it works:[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/0ft019xj/72/)
See this where it doesn't: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/0ft019xj/78/)

I think I need to use `fullCalendar('render');` but even with that, code didn't seem to work right inside the click function. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears fullCalendar won't render if any of its parents have `display: none;`. [The `render` method you referenced](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/) is just the what you need to use, but you need to do so just **after** the model is displayed.

Alternately you could try something to leave the model with `display: block;`, but positioned off screen (`left: -1000%; right: 1000%;` or the like) until you want it visible.

Comment: THANKS i put render function after display block like you suggested and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did to make it work in your modal version.
I created a function as you suspected that adds the calendar into the modal and called it when the "mark Vacation" button is clicked.

```
$('#vacaBtn').click(function () {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      renderCalendars();
});
```

I put all the code that creates the three calendars inside the renderCalendars() function so that they get added into the modal after the modal shows up.

```
function renderCalendars() {
   $('#calendar0').fullCalendar({
    header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultDate: moment(y+"-"+(m+1)+"-"+d),
      theme: true,
      dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

    }
    });

    $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
    header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultDate: moment(y+"-"+(m+2)+"-"+d),

    theme: true
    });
    $('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
           theme: true,
        defaultDate: moment(y+"-"+(m+3)+"-"+d)
    });
}
```